# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, unicorn

Follow rails one app click deployment. Database done well, even I check rails console everything working fine.

Ruby version is 2.3.0 and rails version is 5.0.1

But when I hit IP address it gives an error time out

on check unicorn logs I get

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2017-02-26T15:47:18.969274 #9861] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11928 exit 1> worker=2
I, [2017-02-26T15:47:18.969471 #9861]  INFO -- : worker=2 spawning...
I, [2017-02-26T15:47:18.974112 #11942]  INFO -- : worker=2 spawned pid=11942
I, [2017-02-26T15:47:18.978540 #11936]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2017-02-26T15:47:18.986558 #11938]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

and nginx error is

```
017/02/26 15:34:17 [error] 18564#0: *31 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 121.52.156.57, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock:/", host: "188.166.157.124"
2017/02/26 15:35:42 [error] 32360#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 119.155.34.115, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "188.166.157.124"
2017/02/26 15:42:38 [error] 6296#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 119.152.140.90, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "188.166.157.124"
```

unicorn.conf

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/company_startup"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

ps aux | grep unicor

```
rails     4751 18.0  4.2 172880 21516 ?        R    14:59   0:00 unicorn worker[2] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
rails     4757  0.0  4.1 172404 20972 ?        Rl   14:59   0:00 unicorn worker[3] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
rails     4760  0.0  2.9 159860 14568 ?        Rl   14:59   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
root      4764  0.0  0.1  11712   620 pts/0    S+   14:59   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn
root     20463  0.4  2.6 146740 13176 ?        Sl   04:32   2:48 unicorn master -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production
```

nginx file here:

```
upstream app_server {
server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
```

}

```
server {
listen   80;
root /home/rails/company_startup/public;
server_name _;
index index.htm index.html;
client_max_body_size 1M;
location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                try_files $uri @app;
        }

 location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
}
```

Comment: please read this throughly http://haidrali.com/lets-debug-nginx-unicorn-errors/ let me know if this didn't work

Comment: I show you my unicorn file also

Comment: thats not work :(

Comment: lets debug this first check your unicorn process is running or not run `ps aux | grep unicorn` do reply

Comment: because if your unicorn file is giving error it means it when you start your unicorn process it immediately get stopped please check

Comment: udpated question :) please check

Comment: your unicorn process seems to working find also nginx is connecting to right  sock file, now make sure that your application is running on production mode smoothly test it on your local machine

Comment: yes its working on local machine

Comment: do this `tail -f /path_to_your_unicorn_log_file` this will open unicorn log in tail in a separate tab restart the unicorn and see it log throw any error, also keep that log open with tail and hit your site via browser and see if it throw any error

Comment: @HaseebAhmad pls add `nginx.conf`

Comment: @itsnikolay added

Comment: @HaseebAhmad do you deploy with `capistrano` ?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad and add result of `ls -lahtr /var/run` from the server

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 17  2014 /var/run -> /run

Comment: no capistrano....

Comment: @HaseebAhmad Can you modify unicorn & nginx conf with tcp instead of unix sockets & try again ?
it is for  confirmation

Comment: tcp ? sorry can you help me how?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an unicorn restart problem. You said you don't use capistrano. How do you deploy your application?

EDIT

Unicorn makes better use of resources available to you using multi-process architecture. When it starts, the worker loads the ruby environment and then spawns workers that handles the requests. The master never handles the request, always the workers.

When a worker takes too long, the master can kill it and starts a new worker again.

You seem to use 4 workers. I don't know the size of your droplet on DO, but it seems that the master can't start anymore workers. Could you tell me the size of your droplet (CPU & memory)?

I would install the [unicorn-worker-killer gem](https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer) and test the application again. This should restart your workers in a more effective way than the unicorn master.

EDIT 2:
If this doesn't work, could you try replacing your upstream line with this in your nginx conf file:

```
upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080  fail_timeout=0; }
```

And this in your unicorn conf file:

```
listen "127.0.0.1:8080
```

And restart nginx then unicorn.

EDIT 3:

I think I got it

Could you please change your files like this :

unicorn.conf

```
listen "/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/company_startup"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

Nginx file

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  root /home/rails/company_startup/public;
  server_name <PLEASE PUT YOUR SERVER NAME>;
  index index.htm index.html;
  client_max_body_size 1M;

  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
}
```

Restart unicorn (Make sure to replace the values between <>)

```
kill -s QUIT $(< /var/run/unicorn.pid)
bundle exec unicorn -c <PATH TO unicorn.conf FILE> -E <RAILS ENVIRONMENT> -D
```

Then restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I deploy using ruby on rails click on deploy

Comment: Are you using Digital Ocean, then? A bit more info would be nice!

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean

Comment: meanz i create droplet of ruby on rails...then take clone from github

Comment: When you finished the tutorial, was everything working? Hopefully you checked. Then, did you make any change to your application? Could you try restarting unicorn?

Comment: Did you try the answer above in my last edit? If it works for you, could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: Did if fix your problem?